# How to use different font types for math text and regular text using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am using the *ieeconf* latex class to write a document. To generate the plots for the document, I use *matplotlib 1.2*. For some reason, the ieeconf class uses *Times* font for regular text and *Computer modern roman* for math text. If in matplotlib I use the following *matplotlibrc* file

```
font.family         : serif
font.serif          : Times
text.usetex         : True
```

the regular text (non-math) in the plots looks exactly like the regular text in the rest of the document. However, the math text in the plots looks different to the math text in the document. If instead I use `font.serif : Computer Modern Roman`, then the roles are reversed, and the math texts look identical, but the regular ones look different.

How can I make matplotlib use one font type for the regular text, and another font type for the math text?

Comment: As of version 3.4, you can do this with the `math_fontfamily` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Matplotlib you can give Latex commands using: `rc('text.latex', preamble = [r''])` (sort of like they do it [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/pgf.html#custom-preamble)). Then [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5675/how-to-change-math-font-only) may help you out.

Comment: I don't mind the green checkmark next to the answer, but can you post the actual code you used? I feel that my answer is pointing in the right direction, but some actual code would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

As of [version 3.4](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.4.0.html#math-fontfamily-parameter-to-change-text-font-family), you can do this with the `math_fontfamily` parameter:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 5))

# A simple plot for the background.
ax.plot(range(11), color="0.9")

# A text mixing normal text and math text.
msg = (r"Normal Text. $Text\ in\ math\ mode:\ "
       r"\int_{0}^{\infty } x^2 dx$")

# Set the text in the plot.
ax.text(1, 7, msg, size=12, math_fontfamily='cm')

# Set another font for the next text.
ax.text(1, 3, msg, size=12, math_fontfamily='dejavuserif')

# *math_fontfamily* can be used in most places where there is text,
# like in the title:
ax.set_title(r"$Title\ in\ math\ mode:\ \int_{0}^{\infty } x^2 dx$",
             math_fontfamily='stixsans', size=14)

# Note that the normal text is not changed by *math_fontfamily*.
plt.show()
```

[image]